# How to save 3D objects in viewport to a file and open it late?

Tags: c#, wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

I have added different types of 3D objects in HelixViewport3D. My question is how to save 3D objects/models in a file and open it late, like a typical CAD application.

HelixViewport3D is user defined in a control UserControl.xaml.

The UserControl is defiend as following:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SubWindows.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:HelixToolkit="clr-namespace:HelixToolkit.Wpf;assembly=HelixToolkit.Wpf"
         Height="350" Width="525" MouseRightButtonDown="OnMouseRightButtonDown" TabIndex="0" MouseMove="UserControl_MouseMove" Opacity="1">
<Grid>
<HelixToolkit:HelixViewport3D x:Name="ViewPort" ZoomExtentsWhenLoaded="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <HelixToolkit:SunLight Brightness="0.4" Ambient="0.1" />
        <ModelVisual3D Content="{Binding Model}"/>
        <ModelVisual3D x:Name="SolidModels"/>
        <ModelVisual3D x:Name="ScreenLineModels"/>
        <ModelVisual3D x:Name="DimLinesModels"/>
        <ModelVisual3D x:Name="TagsModels"/>
    </HelixToolkit:HelixViewport3D>
    <Canvas Name="TagsOverlay" IsHitTestVisible="False" ClipToBounds="False"/>
    <Canvas Name="DimsOverlay" IsHitTestVisible="False" ClipToBounds="False" />
</Grid>
```

The save file event is as follows:

```
    private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        saveFileDialog.Filter = "pvp Files (*.pvp)|*.pvp|Text Files (*.xaml)|*.xaml|All Files (*.*)|*.*";

        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string FileName = saveFileDialog.FileName;
            string fileNameExtention = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileName);
            fileNameExtention = fileNameExtention.ToLower();
            if (fileNameExtention == ".xaml")
            {
                uc.ViewPort.Export(FileName);
            }
        }
    }
```

"us" is an instance of UserControl1, defined as UserControl1 uc = new UserControl1(); When I saveToolStripMenuItem_Click to save a file, there is an error as snapshot below.

[image]

But portion of the ViewPort was saved in xaml format.

Any comments to resolve the problem will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to export your viewport3D by using an Export() [e.g. viewport.Export(/sample.xaml) method of Helix Vieport3D, which will give you an XAML file(if you export the model into .xaml) with the key value,
Later add that exported XAML file into your project directory and use below code.

Code of UserConrol.xaml file

```
   <UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="<Path towards your exported xaml file>\sample.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>

</UserControl.Resources>
```

Code for importing XAML file

```
  HelixViewport3D viewport;   //Extra viewport to store the childrens
        viewport= (HelixViewport3D)FindResource("Model");
         // "Model" is the key value of my exported XAML file

        List<Visual3D> items = new List<Visual3D>();    // List is use to store the childrens of ResourceDirectories xaml. 

        //Adds the children inside List
        for (int i=(viewport.Children.Count - 1);i>=0;i--)
        {
            items.Add(viewport.Children[i]);
            viewport.Children.RemoveAt(i);
        }

        //viewport3D.Children.Clear();

        foreach(Visual3D item in items)
        {
            viewport3D.Children.Add(item);
        }
```